# How long does shrimp paste last in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, asian-cuisine

Basically, I have some shrimp paste, it's a nice, very dark purple colour, and I keep it in the fridge.  It's not "dry", but it's dry enough to be extremely firm when I take some out of the jar with a teaspoon.

I'm wondering how long it will last - since it's mostly salt and is very, very thoroughly cooked when used, I'm thinking it will last quite a few months, but would it last a year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grew up in a fishing village and making shrimp paste is one thing we do for a living. The good manufacturing practices we observe keep our shrimp paste in good condition for a year and a half. I don’t even put it in a refrigerator.

Comment: Keeping it at room temperature really doesn't sound safe...

Comment: @Jefromi: Which probably led to the preservation-technique of making shrimp paste, especially when refrigerators weren't available.

Comment: "anything that could happen to it, already did happen to it" ;) The question is how well anything else in the fridge will stay taste when there is shrimp paste around :)

Answer (score 4):

As your shrimp paste is mostly salty, it will last quite a while even without refrigeration. IMHO, it is better to keep it in the fridge as you do. The important thing to remember is to seal it well to cut down on odor leakage. In this way it can sit finely in the fridge over a year.

Comment: Screwing the lid on securely is NOT optional, indeed - it *stinks* until it's been cooked!